solana sendRawTransaction sometimes fail, sometimes success
i got a problem when i broadcast the rawTransaction by the solana-api.
it always return the txHash for me and it correct for the calculate first signature. but i can't found it on the explorer, and my account nothings change.
i add the combudget instruction and add the mev-fee instruction in my rawTransaction.
i wonder what's the fields affect the tx confirmed?  i'm sure my sol balance is correct.

Please share more information if you want more support. For example you can paste it in Solana Explorer and Simulate / Inspect.
Couple of reasons I can think of is - you are not actually Sending the Transaction or you are checking on the wrong network i.e. You sent on Devnet but you are checking on Testnet.

